# Can I make photodiode's voltage output bipolar?

Tags: photodiode

I am trying to detect light with photodiode. Currently, I am planning to build a circuit like one of the followings:

[image]

Two circuits' output will swing between 0 to Vcc volts.

What I want is, I want to make an output swing -A to A volts.
For better understanding, please note the following figure:

[image]

In the figures, **original signal** is a brightness of light signal and **NRZ coding** will be the output of photodetecting circuit, and the input of ADC.

So, the problem is, **Can I build a photodetecting circuit which converts `unipolar waveform of light` into `bipolar NRZ waveform of voltage`?**

**NOTE:** The ADC is originally used for RF signals and antennas which outputs NRZ signal. Therefore, you don't need to worry about *How ADC accepts negative voltage input?*

Comment: How DC balanced is your NRZ data signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this trivially by replacing the 0v rail with your negative rail; the output will thus swing between the negative and positive rails. How close it gets to those rails depends on the light input, your photodiode's characteristics, and the resistor; it will not be a neat square wave, but will require squaring up with a comparator.

Since your data is using NRZ coding, which guarantees you'll see a certain minimum rate of edges, you could also use AC coupling to achieve this without a negative rail:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHh4en.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. According to [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZlD9RdJhEA), I need at least two power supply to make a negative voltage source, is it right? I will try it. I think power supply of mine can do this.

Comment: Yes, or a power supply module that provides both positive and negative rails. If you're feeding it into a bipolar ADC, though, you must already have a negative reference.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick says you can just AC-couple the signal and it will go bipolar, without an additional supply (but you'll need a negative supply to be able to use the signal).

This may work with really, really slow signals and bright illumination (eg. a laser) but if you have fast signals and/or low light levels then you should really use a transimpedance amplifier to reduce the effect of the pole caused by the PD capacitance and load resistance.